# In TypeScript, when do you use "let" and when do you use "const"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In TypeScript, when do you use "let" and when do you use "const"?

Comment: You use `const` unless you know you'll be changing the value later and have a damn good reason.

Comment: I use them when I want to declare variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`const` stands for `constant`, and it means the variable cannot be reassigned at a later time.

`let` is similar to `var` except that it is block scoped, which means it can be declared inside of a `for` loop and will be local to the body of that `for` loop (and therefor does not exist outside of it)

The latter is different from a `var` variable which can be declared anywhere but is always local to the function scope.

In general it is good practice to try and define your variables as `const` as much as possible.

Comment: Worth noting - this is not specific only to TypeScript, but for JavaScript in general since ECMAScript 2015 is the standard now.

Comment: @AdrianWydmanski I'd go ever further and say it applies to any language that provides `const`/`let` or `val`/`var` or `final`/not.

Answer (score 4):

As I meanwhile do almost exclusivey functional programming I find the destinction between `const` and `let` pretty useless.
I never ever reassign values to names. Never - regardless of the language.

Having said that I find the usage problematic due to 2 reasons.

- `const` is longer than `let` (no seriously!)
- `const` sort of communicates back: **Hey! I am constant** but that is not true (well it is, but ...) I had multiple times collegues that were totally surprised

that this is possible

```
const x = { foo: "bar" }
x["foo"] = "Not bar!"
```

Sure the name and its reference is const but the object referenced is not. Granted in Typescript you can at least create

```
type ROO = Readonly<SomeType>
const x: ROO = someReferenceValue
x.someProp = "A wanna be a bar!" //compile error
```

So for Typescript `const` finally could mean `const`

Comment: Your second point is correct TypeScript is wrong to recommend that `const` is used for all variables unless re-assignment is expected (see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html let vs const), as this is NOT what constant means in most programming languages. ECMA6 examples all have the "expected" usage (const pi = 3.14159) - whereby we could imagine all constants being replaced by primitive values at compile time. Using `const` for variables is contradiction in terms. TypeScript should restrict the ECMA6 usage to stop `const` being applied to complex types.