# Benefit of const vs let in TypeScript (or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, resharper

I was reading the [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/const.html) and I see that both `let` and `const` are block scoped, which is great. Obviously, a const cannot be changed (it is immutable). But why is ReSharper is encouraging me to change as many `let`s to `const` as I can? I'm assuming ReSharper thinks there is a performance gain in using `const` over `let`? Is there a speed difference between `const` and `let`? Is there a different reason to use `const`? Take the following example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.InputControl.ParentQuestions.length; i++) {
    const id = this.InputControl.ParentQuestions[i].ParentId;
    const value = this.InputControl.ParentQuestions[i].ParentRequiredAnswer;
    if (!formVals[id]) return false;
    if (formVals[id].toLowerCase() != value.toLowerCase()) return false;
}
```

Previously, I had `let id` and `let value` but ReSharper asked me to change them to `const`, which works, but why is it better in this case? Or in any case?

I also found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858743/in-typescript-when-do-you-use-let-and-when-do-you-use-const), but it talks more about what `let` and `const` do, not so much why one is better than the other. It does say to use `const` as much as possible, but what benefit does that provide?

Comment: since in this respect IMO there is no difference between TS and JS, I will add JS tag too.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I agree with [Giorgi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275537/1906307) that performance is not the main reason. A code analyzer could just as well determine that a variable declared with `let` is not ever reassigned and optimize it the same as if you had declared it with `const`. (Heck, linters have rules to detect this and suggest using `const` instead of `let`.)

Yes, it does signal to the reader that you're not going to assign to the variable. The benefit of `const`, over putting a comment saying the same thing, is mainly that `const` is a standard way of signalling it. Being standard, it transmits the information more readily than custom comments. (Also, a comment could be wrong but `const` won't let you be wrong.) I don't think this is the main benefit though.

The "principle of least privilege" is often invoked in conjunction with `const`, but why should I care about the least privilege? Because **it helps with early detection of coding mistakes**. Consider the following code:

```
function findSomethingInDocument(document) {
    let tree = getTreeFromDocument(document); // We get some sort of tree structure.
    let found;
    for (const child of tree.children) {
        if (child.someFlag) {
            tree = child; // Oops I meant found = child :(
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

In this code, I typed `tree = child` when I meant to type `found = child`. Yes, the bug *can* be found in testing. But why wait for testing? I never meant `tree` to be changed. If I had marked it `const` then I would have *immediately learned the error* because the compiler would informed me of it. I would not have to wait for testing. The code above is fairly simple but imagine a more complicated algorithm that uses more variables.

Comment: Plus 1 for the example :-)

Comment: Thansk for comprehensive answer. It should still be noted that const vs. let is a problem for hello worlds and meaningless in a large scope. If you ever run your code before commiting it, you will notice the possible bugs. When another developer has access to the source, he/she can change the definition and be completely oblivious of any nit-picking grade of immutability. This happens all the time.

Answer (score 16):

When you have a variable which can be declared as `const`, and you declare it as such you inform the reader that you don't plan to reassign it to a different value later on.

Also by declaring a variable `const` it means you have thought up front that you don't plan to reassign it, which in turn can protect you from accidental bugs or errors.