# When should I use "var", "let" and "const" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I just start coding in TypeScript. So please excuse my newbie question.

I have this method:

```
public copyToDest() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.source.length; i++) {
        var item = this.source[i];
        if (item && item.isValid)
            this.dest.push(item);
    }
}
```

Which is working fine. After installing a refactoring tool, I got 2 suggestions:

1. Change `var i = 0;` to `let i = 0;`
2. Change `var item = ...` to `const item = ...`

Is there any rule I'm missing about proper use of `var`, `let` and `const`? Or should I just ignore these suggestions?

Comment: Related: [In TypeScript, when do you use “let” and when do you use “const”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38858743/in-typescript-when-do-you-use-let-and-when-do-you-use-const)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `let` when the variable's value can be changed.

Use `const` when the variable's value cannot/should not be changed.

Do not use `var`.

Comment: @Vladimir830 -- No, but `var` is considered conceptually flawed by many, in that its declaration is always moved to the top of the current function scope. `let` was introduced to offer a more sensible alternative without breaking code that already relies on the original behavior of `var`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)